# create a new column with passwords using crypt

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, crypt, pgcrypto

I am currently trying to create a new column with passwords based on other column from the same table (tb_customer).
The source to create the passwords is the column cust_cif.

The script I used is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE erp.tb_customer 
  ADD COLUMN password CHAR (34) USING crypt(erp.tb_customer.cust_cif, gen_salt('md5'));
```

I am getting an error and don't know why, since md5 doesn't need installation (but I did nevertheless).

The error is the following:

```
ERROR:  does not exist type «crypt»
LINE 2:   ADD COLUMN password crypt(erp.tb_customer.cust_cif, gen_sa...
```

I also tried with

```
ALTER TABLE erp.tb_customer 
  ADD COLUMN password SELECT crypt(erp.tb_customer.cust_cif, gen_salt('md5'));
```

Here are some values shown in the table `tb_customer`:

cust_no | cust_name | cust_cif | last_updated_by | last_updated_date

```
"C0001" "PIENSOS MARTIN"    "A12345678" "SYSTEM"    "2022-04-28"
"C0002" "AGRICULTURA VIVES" "A66666666" "SYSTEM"    "2022-04-28"
"C0003" "CULTIVOS MARAVILLA"    "A55555555" "SYSTEM"    "2022-04-28"
"C0004" "ASOCIADOS PEREZ"   "A23126743" "SYSTEM"    "2022-04-28"
"C0005" "TECNICOS AVA"  "B34211233" "SYSTEM"    "2022-04-28"
"C0006" "AGR AGRI"  "B78788999" "SYSTEM"    "2022-04-28"
"C0007" "AGRIMARCOS"    "B98766562" "SYSTEM"    "2022-04-28"
"C0008" "CULTIVANDO ALEGRIA"    "B12333123" "SYSTEM"    "2022-04-28"
"C0009" "MARCOS LIMPIEZA"   "A87727711" "SYSTEM"    "2022-04-28"
"C0010" "VIAJES MUNDO"  "A00099982" "SYSTEM"    "2022-04-28"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have use USING in your statement, to tell the database how and where to collect the data for this column. Data type is also missing in your statement. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens, you mean ```ADD COLUMN password SELECT crypt(erp.tb_customer.cust_cif, gen_salt('md5')) USING ...```? And after 'USING' what expression should I add?

Comment: Share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So that community users can reproduce the problem & respond with verifiable answers quickly.

Comment: @जलजनक, you are right, sorry, I edited and added some values

Comment: Did you read the manual? You can see that after "password" you didn't mention a data type. USING is also missing. Check the manual

Comment: @FrankHeikens, I read the manual but as you can see, unfortunately, I am not able to understand well what is meant. I am starting with SQL. You are right, I forgot the data type, which is STRING.  The expression you are referring to is this: ```ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name [ SET DATA ] TYPE data_type [ COLLATE collation ] [ USING expression ]``` so I just can think about ```ADD COLUMN password STRING USING crypt(erp.tb_customer.cust_cif, gen_salt('md5'))``` But I know something is missing

Comment: STRING is not a valid data type: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens, thank you, ```CHAR(34)``` being 'md5' the algorithm: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no `ADD COLUMN...USING`.

You will have to add the column and populate it (UPDATE) in different statements. Possibly in the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
ALTER TABLE erp.tb_customer 
ADD COLUMN password_cryp char(100);

--CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE erp.col_cryp() AS $$
DECLARE
  _row record;
BEGIN
    FOR _row IN (
        SELECT cust_cif FROM erp.tb_customer
        )
    LOOP
        UPDATE erp.tb_customer
        SET password_cryp = crypt('cust_cif', gen_salt('md5'));
    END LOOP;
END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CALL erp.col_cryp();
```

To test it you can try:

```
SELECT ("password_cryp " = 'copy here the generated code on the table') AS IsMatch FROM erp.tb_customer;
```

Hope it works!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).